# How to Export Excel File into .xlsx extension in AngularJs with MVC

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

//// Here Design Part

```
<a class="btn btn-success" style="margin-bottom:10px;" 
   ng-click="exporttoexcel(polist)">Export to Excel</a>
```

//// Here angular Controller file to Fetch id and pass it to the MVC Controller

```
var exportlist = [];
$scope.exporttoexcel = function (data) {
    debugger;
    var array = [];
    for (var i in data) {
        if (data[i].Selected == true) {
            array.push(data[i].POID);
        }
    }
    debugger;
    var PoIDS = array.toString();
    window.location.href = "/Order/Export?id=" + PoIDS;
};
```

/////// Now this part is `MVC` Controller where we fetch Record and create 
        ExcelFile (I Want to save this from `.xlsx` Extension but it cant open),
        But when i change extension to `xls` it working and open Perfectly But my 
        Boss need to open in `.xlsx` Please

```
public ActionResult Export(string id = "")
{
    var list = orderApi.Exportorder(id).ToList();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    string sFileName = "PurchaseOrder.XLSX";
    sb.Append("<table style='1px solid black; font-size:12px;' border='1'>");
    sb.Append("<tr>");
    sb.Append("<td><b> POnumber </b></td>");
    sb.Append("<td><b> Itemnumber </b></td>");
    //sb.Append("<td><b> Marking </b></td>");
    sb.Append("<td><b> Partnumber</b> </td>");
    sb.Append("<td><b> DescriptionEN </b></td>");
    sb.Append("<td><b> DescriptionCN </b></td>");
    sb.Append("<td><b> MaterialEN </b></td>");
    sb.Append("<td><b> MaterialCN</b> </td>");
    sb.Append("<td><b> Remark</b> </td>");
    sb.Append("<td><b> CTNS</b> </td>");
    sb.Append("<td><b> Packing</b> </td>");
    sb.Append("<td><b> Unit </b></td>");
    sb.Append("<td><b> Quantity </b></td>");
    sb.Append("<td><b> UnitPriceRMB</b></td>");
    sb.Append("<td><b> AmountUSD</b> </td>");
    sb.Append("<td><b> L</b> </td>");
    sb.Append("<td><b> W </b></td>");
    sb.Append("<td><b> H </b></td>");
    sb.Append("<td><b> Weight </b></td>");
    sb.Append("<td><b> Status</b> </td>");
    sb.Append("<td><b> StatusRemark</b> </td>");
    sb.Append("</tr>");
    if (list != null)
    {
        foreach (var data in list)
        {
            sb.Append("<tr>");
            sb.Append("<td>" + data.POID + "</td>");
            sb.Append("<td>" + data.OIID + "</td>");
            //sb.Append("<td></td>");
            sb.Append("<td>" + data.PartNo + "</td>");
            sb.Append("<td>" + data.ItemDesc_en + "</td>");
            sb.Append("<td>" + data.ItemDesc_ch + "</td>");
            sb.Append("<td>" + data.Material_en + "</td>");
            sb.Append("<td>" + data.Material_ch + "</td>");
            sb.Append("<td>" + data.ItemRemark + "</td>");
            sb.Append("<td>" + data.CTN + "</td>");
            sb.Append("<td>" + data.Packing + "</td>");
            sb.Append("<td>" + data.Unit + "</td>");
            sb.Append("<td>" + data.Quantity + "</td>");
            sb.Append("<td>" + data.UnitPriceRMB + "</td>");
            sb.Append("<td>" + data.Amount + "</td>");
            sb.Append("<td>" + data.L + "</td>");
            sb.Append("<td>" + data.W + "</td>");
            sb.Append("<td>" + data.H + "</td>");
            sb.Append("<td>" + data.Weight + "</td>");
            sb.Append("<td>" + data.ItemStatus + "</td>");
            sb.Append("<td>" + data.RemarkInt + "</td>");
            sb.Append("</tr>");
        }
    }
    sb.Append("</table>");

    HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; 
        filename=" + sFileName);
    this.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
    return File(buffer, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
}
```

///// When it download it cant Open it getting Extension Error ...
      Please anyone help me to create and open it ..
      Thanks 
     [image]

Comment: have you checked with postman if your api is working?

Comment: Postman?..Yes its working with .xls Extension But i need .xlsx Extension

Comment: [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) can be used to test you api's by the way look like problem is with your api method

Answer (score 0):

For xlsx You have to change your content type to `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` something like

```
this.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
```

[Find full list here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsofficedeveloper/2008/05/08/office-2007-file-format-mime-types-for-http-content-streaming-2/)

Comment: Its Not Working.. It still getting same things

Comment: As per [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/67a0b8ba-08a7-4e1a-93e7-3985a8b7f31f/c-string-builder-to-create-excel-2010-question?forum=csharpgeneral) It appears you are creating a file name with the extension .xlsx, but trying to give the file html.  You must either supply valid .xlsx info in the file or use some other format

Comment: I am passing just Datatable value in that and when we change extension into .xls its Working Perfect and open or show data but i need to open in .xlsx extension